# How to rewrite this without using map function

Tags: python, python-3.x

You have a list of list and trying to convert it to a dictionary that maps names of athletes to lists of their jump length, the jumps also need to be converted to int.

I found a solution, but it uses the function maps and to be honest I don't get how maps work well enough.
Whats another way to solve this problem (the more basic the better)

```
jumps = [
    ['Student', 'Jump 1', 'Jump 2', 'Jump 3'],
    ['James', '10', '9', '8'],
    ['Finn', '18', '19', '21'],
    ['Blu', '14', '15', '17'],
    ['John', '15', '16', '16'],
    ['Kim', '13', '19', '13'],
    ['Lacey', '19', '17', '10']]

def jump_distance(jumps):
    dict = {}
    for d in jumps[1:]:
        dict[d[0]] = list(map(int, d[1:]))
    return dict
```

Feel free to explain how this works as well:

```py
dict[d[0]] = list(map(int, d[1:]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes *comprehensions* can make the code both more succinct and easier to read.

In this case, if we know that `jumps` will have the structure in the example, with the first element containing the headings and the remaining elements containing the data, then we could solve the problem using an outer dictionary comprehension and an inner list comprehension as follows.

```py
def jump_distances(jumps):
    return {jump[0]: [int(d) for d in jump[1:]] for jump in jumps[1:]}
```

With the list in your example, this returns:

```
{
  'James': [10, 9, 8],
  'Finn': [18, 19, 21],
  'Blu': [14, 15, 17],
  'John': [15, 16, 16],
  'Kim': [13, 19, 13],
  'Lacey': [19, 17, 10]
}
```

To answer your other question, `list(map(int, d[1:]))` maps each element in the sub-list `d[1:]` to whatever the function `int` returns with that element as an argument. For example:

```py
def stars(n):
    return "*" * n

for x in map(stars, [1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
```

outputs

```
*
**
***
```

`map` actually doesn't return a list, but it is easy enough to convert what it returns to a list using `list`. The following two expressions produce the same list, but I think the second is more readable.

```py
list(map(stars, [1, 2, 3]))
[stars(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]]
```

(Both expressions produce the list `['*', '**', '***']`.)

Comment: This is really a great explanation for understanding the real use case of the map function.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict[d[0]] = list(map(int, d[1:]))
    
map(int, d[1:]) -> map(function, iterable)
                -> function is "int"
                -> iterable is d[1:]
                -> here "d" contains [['James', '10', '9', '8'],
                                            ['Finn', '18', '19', '21'],
                                            ['Blu', '14', '15', '17'],
                                            ['John', '15', '16', '16'],
                                            ['Kim', '13', '19', '13'],
                                            ['Lacey', '19', '10', '10']]. 
                -> And d[1:] means [['10', '9', '8'],
                                            ['18', '19', '21'],
                                            ['14', '15', '17'],
                                            ['15', '16', '16'],
                                            ['13', '19', '13'],
                                            ['19', '19', '10']].
```

So the map module applies "int" function on each element in d[1:]. For instance, if we consider the first element in the list d[1:], then the values would be 10 - int, 9 - int, 8 - int.

If you change "['James', '10', '9', '8']" to "['James', '10', 'dd', '8']", then map will fail. because, "dd" is not valid value to apply "int" datatype.

Hope you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```py
def jump_distance(jumps):
    dict = {}
    for d in jumps[1:]:
        dict[d[0]] = [int(i) for i in d[1:]]  # convert to int
    return dict
```

Answer (score 0):

What `map` does in your example is this: we get jump distances as strings so for any manipulation we probably want to convert then to numeric values. So then:

`d[1:]` - is a slice of one of your input lists from the second element to the end, like so: `['10', '9', '8']`

`map(int, d[1:])` - this converts elements of iterable (the slice above) to integers, although a float would be a better choice IMO.

Finally, `map` returns a mapper object so in order to produce our values we need to exhaust the mapper which we do by calling `list()` on it.